# Add dropdownmenu - button to gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to figure out how I can add a button to my grid-view that when clicked a drop down menu is formed with options that are clickable and will fire some kind of event.

[image below relevant may help somewhat conceptualize the location of the button]

The issue is that it will not show up when a row is added or in any way what so ever.

Here's my code:

```
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdvwDepositTransaction"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Status"
                OnRowCommand="grdvwDepositTransaction_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound"
                CssClass="grid">

               <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <ul id="actionMenuHomeScreenPanel" style="display: none; margin-top: -6px; text-align: left; " onmouseover="javascript: showMenu(); return false;" onmouseout="javascript: hideMenu(); return false;" class="ui-menu">
               <li><a href="#" onclick="window.close();">Cancel</a></li>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="btnValidateTotals_Click" Text="Validate Transactions" width="100px"></asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
               </ul>
                      </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>                      
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DepositEntry.cardNumber" HeaderText="Card Number" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DepositEntry.accountNumber" HeaderText="Account Number" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DepositEntry.taxID" HeaderText="Tax ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DepositEntry.firstName" HeaderText="Customer Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DepositEntry.transactionDateTime" HeaderText="Transaction Date/Time" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DepositEntry.cashAmount" HeaderText="Cash Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DepositEntry.depositAmount" HeaderText="Envelope Deposit Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
               </Columns>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <span style="font-weight: bold; text-anchor:middle;">No Transactions have been entered</span>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>                   
            </asp:GridView>
```

[image: Trying To Make A Button that fills this requirement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TemplateField. Look this example

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Administração">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdministracao" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Administracao") %>' Width="90px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="Ativo" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="False" Text="Bloqueado" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Image ID="imgAdministracao" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# (Eval("Administracao").Equals(true) ? "Image/OK.png" : (Eval("Administracao").Equals(false) ? "Image/no.png" : "~/Image/blank.gif"))%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I want it to display a menu that will allow me to select edit or delete the row. Will this allow me to do this?